# Why are StackExchange "hot questions" now invisible?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

[image]

I used to click on "Hot Questions" in the top bar as I am fond of them. But I cannot do that now ever since the top bar was redesigned. I now have to visit https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot for that.

Why was it removed? And are there plans to bring it back?

Comment: No they are not invisible. Just scroll the page and see on the right column